# ajax not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi I am trying to call a file named load.php and retrieve the result through AJAX. But for reasons which I dont know, my code is not working. Here is my code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   cache:false
})
var ajax_load="<img src='loading.gif' alt='loading...' />";
var loadurl = "load.php";
$("#add").click(function(){
   $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadurl, null, function(responsetext){
       alert("response text: "+responsetext);
   });
});
```

`add` is the id of my button and `result` is the id of my div where I want the result.

By the time server is fetching the result I wanted the loading gif image to be running and when the loading has complete the content shud be displayed.

Also, I did not want the cache option to be set, so I made it false.

I have included all the necessary libraries and the files in the correct path. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What's not working? What error are you getting?

Comment: Do you have firebug? You can see the error message there. It really can help you to debug your ajax.

Comment: i am not getting any error lik. there is no response from the server... @Nick

Comment: am really sorry. i ve never heard of firebug. ll find it now though. tahnk u. @bhoo-day

Comment: the problem was solved when i enclosed the click function for the button in $(function){ }

Answer (score 0):

For posterity sake (considering the answer seems to have been resolved in the comments). The issue appears to have been a result of attempting to access the DOM prior to it being ready.

```
$("#add").click(function(){
  // Code...
});
```

The above code relies on the element with id "add" (I.E. `<a href='#' id='add'></a>`) existing in the DOM so that the function passed to click can be attached to its click event.

An essential way to avoid attempting to attach to an element's event before the element becomes available is to wait for the entire DOM to load. [jQuery's ready method](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) does this and accepts the code that needs to wait as a function parameter.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#add").click(function(){
    // Code...
  });
});
```

jQuery also overloads the $ method with the same functionality when passed a function. This provides the following convenient shorthand, which is often used instead.

```
$(function(){
  $("#add").click(function(){
    // Code...
  });
});
```